# problem of Configure linux password rules: password shouldn't be the reverse of previous password

Tags: linux, security, configuration, password, pam

I am configuring password rules in linux system(RedHat Enterprise linux 5).
By google, I found that using pam_cracklib will make simple check automatically.
That is, pam_cracklib will automatically check if the new password is the reverse one of the previous password. If yes, it will reject the new password.

However, I tried a new password just the reverse of the previous one, the new password can take effective!
That is, pam_cracklib will allow the new password(reverse of the previous one).
Here is my configuration:

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth:
password    required    pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3  minlen=6
```

Could anyone tell me if there is something wrong with my configuration? Or there are some bugs with pam_cracklib?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to change the password as root or as a regular user? root can override all kinds of restrictions in many situations.

Comment: Janne, I change password as a regular user, not root.So I am surprised why pam_cracklib doesn't take effective.

Comment: adding "obscure" to `pam_cracklib` will have similar effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `try_first_pass` with cracklib. It should check whatever the password is a palindrome or rotation of old password by default.

What's more, other modules (probably pam_unix.so or pam_ldap.so) in the stack *must* use the `use_authok` flag or they will be allowed to ask the user for password if previous module didn't accept the provided password.

In short, try:

```
password    required    pam_cracklib.so retry=3  minlen=6
password    required    pam_unix.so use_authok nullok md5
```

The `nullok` flag tells the module it's OK to change password from an empty one (the usual method of forcing a password change in UNIX systems), you can remove it if you don't use this functionality.

Comment: But It seems the method you proposed still can't solve the problem.

Comment: For example, if I first set passwd:1qaz2wsx, the second I set passwd:xsw2zaq1. It works. So the rotation checking seems doesn't take effective.

Comment: The palindrome is just for a new password (you can't have a "qwertrewq" password). Rotation checks only for simple word rotation, as when you start a word in the middle and add the start to the end: so with old password "password", the new password can't be "sswordpa" or "wordpass". As such, I don't think you should worry about this combination, it's rather obscure. Anyway, you may be interested in discussion in http://serverfault.com/questions/4221/user-password-age-complexity-policy.

Comment: Hobert, thanks a lot for your help and your suggested webpage.

Comment: In fact, the information by google makes me confused.

Comment: http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html

Comment: Learn from the above http://www.deer-run.com/~hal/sysadmin/pam_cracklib.html, it says: pam_cracklib will check "Is the new password just the old password with the letters reversed ("password" vs. "drowssap") or rotated ("password" vs. "asswordp") "

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggested webpage. It's really great of help!

Comment: The deer-run site is wrong, I too first thought that the module didn't work properly, I got the simple rotation from source code. The exact thing that the module checks is whatever the new password is a substring of the concatenated old password, in the above example, whatever its a substring of "passwordpassword".

Comment: Hubert, thanks a lot for your response. The deer-run site really makes me confused for two days. Thanks ：-）